# In C#, how can i deserialize this json?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, restsharp

I am getting this JSON data back from a REST service that looks like this:

```
[ [ [ {"Name": "Joe", "Comment": "Load", "Updated": null, "Test": ""} ] ] ]
```

or

```
[ [ [ {"Name": "Joe", "Comment": "Load", "Updated": null, "Test": ""}, {"Name": "Bill", "Comment": "123", "Updated": null, "Test": ""} ] ] ]
```

I did a "Copy JSON as classes" feature in visual studio and it created this:

```
 public class Rootobject
 {
     public Project[][][] Property1 { get; set; }
 }

 public class Project
 {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Comment { get; set; }
   public string Updated { get; set; }
   public string Test { get; set; }
 }
```

but when i try to deserialize using this code:

```
 var results = new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<Rootobject>(response);
```

I get an error stating:

**An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in RestSharp.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'RestSharp.JsonArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'**

Could you please advise on what I might be doing wrong (NOTE: i don't have any control over how the data comes in so changing the format isn't an option)

Also, to confirm this seems to be valid JSON from JSONLlint:

[image]

Comment: try this site [jason2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) your jason does not look like it's properly formatted either btw

Comment: i tried using jsonlint to confirm it was valid json and it comes back as successfull: http://jsonlint.com/.  I have included a screenshot from jsonlint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize that particular JSON like this using Json.NET:

```
var json = "[ [ [ {\"Name\": \"Joe\", \"Comment\": \"Load\", \"Updated\": null, \"Test\": \"\"}, "+ 
                " {\"Name\": \"Bill\", \"Comment\": \"123\", \"Updated\": null, \"Test\": \"\"} ] ] ]";

var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<List<Project>>>>(json);
```

And to get all the `Project`s from the nested lists:

```
var allProjects = deserializedObject.SelectMany(x => x.SelectMany(y => y)).ToList();
```

Comment: Very nice.  @Szabolcs Seems you got the right answer and there is no need to implement a custom deserializer. ( If this works :) )

Answer (score 2):

Using `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package, 
try

```
JSONConvert.DeserialiseObject<Rootobject>(response)
```

EDIT: BTW, I tried to use your json on http://json2csharp.com/ and it says **Parsing your JSON didn't work. Please make sure it's valid.** So I doubt that any json parsing library will be able to parse your JSON.

However implementing your own deserializer is possible and an ideal solution when external services return invalid JSON

I can probably help you deserialize it if you show me what JSON you get when service returns multiple `Project` objects.

EDIT2: Szabolcs's solutions seems promising, but I would still suggest testing it with JSON for multiple `Product` objects. I smell something bad & its the shitty third party service. Always good to test.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ seems to say that this is valid JSON (i have added a screenshot to the question).  Also, i tried using your code above and i get a similar error as listed in my question

Comment: I can probably help you deserialize it if you show me what JSON you get when service returns multiple **Project** objects.